# Archiving existing task list in Sharepoint 2010 without using Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-list

I have an internal team SharePoint site where the team posts tasks in a task list. Once the task is completed, it is marked COMPLETED. I want to create a workflow so that when I change the status of a task to COMPLETED, the task is removed from the list of team tasks and moved to a new folder/list where all the completed tasks are going to be tracked.

Now, I know I can do this easily using SharePoint Designer by creating a workflow for the team tasks and then applying an equal condition on the status. However, our organization currently doesn't have the ability to use SharePoint designer and the feature is disabled.

How do I achieve the same functionality just by using the on-site features and settings. Any suggestions? I was able to add workflow but I can seem to find the equal condition.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to solve the problem of separating completed and uncompleted tasks is simply to use views based on the task status.

If you MUST move the item to a different location, you can research if Records Management features get you part way, but chances are you'll need to use a tool or write code.